# Serial port - receive bytes count

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, stm32, stm32cubeide

I transmit 256 bytes from stm32 and receive it by SerialPort in Visual studio. Why i receive bytes 2 times? 32 and then 224.

stm32 USART configuration:

```
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
```

```
uint8_t memory[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
memory[i] = 0xFF;
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, memory, sizeof(memory), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

Visual studio:

```
private void readerSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!this.readerSerialPort.IsOpen) return;
  int bytes = this.readerSerialPort.BytesToRead;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
  this.readerSerialPort.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
  MessageBox.Show(buffer.Length.ToString());
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: How many bytes you'll get is entirely unpredictable, whatever happens to be available in the receive buffer by the time you call Read().  Usually only a few bytes, unless you slow down the code by single-stepping with the debugger or have a lot of active threadpool threads.

Comment: There can be other reasons as well. Your STM32 application may do other work during the transmission. For instance if there are any interrupts occur, the transmission is stopped while the interrupt handler is executed.
On the PCs side there are definitely a lot of interrupts occur constantly, and also, there are a lot of other apps being executed by your CPU, not only your serial reader app. The scheduler of the OS can stop your app, and schedules other apps for running.  When your apps is running, it receives some data, when it is running again, it receives another chunk of data.

Comment: For debugging,  use [System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=net-7.0) instead of `MessageBox.Show`

Comment: Also as mentioned in the answer below, send a newline (ie: CR, CRLF, or LF) as the last byte. Ensure that you set the [SerialPort.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and [SerialPort.ReadBufferSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) properties appropriately.  Then you can use [SerialPort.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

Comment: If you ask me, you need a scope and/or logic analyzer to see how exactly your transmission happens. Before you assume it's a software problem, make sure that on a physical level you actually transmit all 256 bytes as a single transmission. Because if not, then you're blaming the wrong thing. You can always keep your PC side app receiving until it receives the correct amount of information or some termination character or sequence of your choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial protocol as well as USB bulk endpoints, which are likely used between the microcontroller and your PC are stream protocols. They assume a constant flow of bytes and do not use delimiters to transmit the boundaries of the original data chunks.

This is opposed to message-oriented protocol that transmit and retain distinct chunks of data.

As a consequence, the size of the chunks you used to submit the data are not retained. Multiple chunks might be joined into a single one, and a single chunk might be split into multiple ones as you have experienced.

If you require a message-oriented protocol, you need to implemented it yourself on top of the stream protocol. Typical approaches are:

- Define a message structure with a message header containing the message length.
- Use delimiters (CR/LF in the simplest case if text data is transmitted).